# How to detect browser disconnect in firebase backend from browser crashes

Tags: firebase

Browsers will send disconnect messages to firebase when they are closed normally but I want to account for crashes.

```
var presenceRef = new Firebase('https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/disconnectmessage');
// Write a string when I lose my connection
presenceRef.onDisconnect().set("I disconnected!");
```

How would I best detect disconnects in firebase from browser crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should work perfectly fine on a browser crash as well as a graceful disconnect.  There may be a slight delay (1-3 minutes) before Firebase detects the client has died, but your .set() should definitely still happen.